# laravel uploading project on cpanel is not running

Tags: laravel

I am deploying laravel project on cpanel but i get error i am uploading folder in root and public folder content move into public_html/demo4 folder. I get error 500 error but when i am moves public folder content to public_html folder it run. is any changes in filesystem.php. I am getting error as

> [27-Jan-2021 10:04:20 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning:  require(/home/indextechno/public_html/demo4/../real/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/indextechno/public_html/demo4/index.php on line 24
> [27-Jan-2021 10:04:20 Etc/GMT] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/indextechno/public_html/demo4/../real/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/indextechno/public_html/demo4/index.php on line 24

Comment: did you run composer dump-autoload?

Comment: can u put your `index.php` from public ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes it will works when stored in public_html but when i create subfolder in public_html/demo4 and store in it. it will not works